# Checkbox reports 'missing' if unchecked with Zend Annotation Builder form isValid()

Tags: php, checkbox, zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm having a trouble getting a checkbox to pass 'isValid' from a form built using Zend Annotation builder with a Doctrine entity.

Even when I don't use a Required annotation and remove the validation, it still reports 'missing' on my checkbox "message": "Required fields are missing or invalid: Content"

Annotation in entity:

```
/**
 * @var boolean $Content
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Content", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"checkbox"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Value:"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"Boolean"})
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"NotEmpty"})
 */
```

Content element in form:

```
Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox::__set_state(array(
   'attributes' => 
  array (
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'name' => 'Content',
  ),
   'validator' => NULL,
   'useHiddenElement' => true,
   'uncheckedValue' => '0',
   'checkedValue' => '1',
   'label' => 'Value:',
   'labelAttributes' => 
  array (
  ),
   'labelOptions' => 
  array (
  ),
   'messages' => 
  array (
  ),
   'options' => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Value:',
  ),
   'value' => '0',
));
```

Any help?

Comment: You do know that checkboxes are only sent by the bowser to the PHP script if they are actually checked dont you.

Comment: 'messages' for that element picks up the value: isEmpty => 'Value is required and can't be empty' after running $form->isValid()

Comment: re: only sent....  
Yes, and technically I'm not setting anything in the browser which is why I removed the 'required' and 'validator' and got the same result. In this particular case, I'm using the zend form to validate ajax data which I bind to the form with an array using $form->setData($data) where $data['Content'] = '0'

Comment: I don't care if it skips empties (on this field) entirely - I'm getting missing whether I have Required set or not, whether I use a validator or not. It's failing with both annotations removed whenever the box is unchecked. It can skip validating that field entirely and I can do it myself, I don't care! At this point it fails whenever unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because of the '0'. Zend thinks that you a passing a false value and the NotEmpty validators throws an error.

`form->getInputFilter()->get('Content')->setContinueIfEmpty(true)` should solve the problem.

Edit: check this articles as well. http://akrabat.com/setting-up-required-fields-that-can-be-empty-with-zendinputfilter/

Comment: ok, but as I stated, I tried it without the notempty validator and got the same result.

Comment: but thankyou, that does the trick - I think I can add that in the annotations, if i can just find the right key